# styled-component by default use !important?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I wrap existing component with styled-component but I find it annoying to have to declare `!important` to overwrite the existing style of that component, for example

```
import { Row, Col, Card, Typography } from 'antd'
const { Title } = Typography

const StyledTitle = styled(Title)`
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 20px 0 !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
`
```

It's hard to see which property have to use important, I detect it via visual changes after I save the file, which is so annoying, what's the solution to this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They recommend adding ampersands

```
const StyledTitle = styled(Title)`
  &&& {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
      font-weight: normal;
  }
`
```

https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity